# Как скачать OpenCV с репозитория для c++ на Linux Debian

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

Как скачать OpenCV с репозитория для c++ на Linux Debian?
Должна быть команда в одну строчку, а ее я позабыл, в интернете не нашел

Answer (score 2):

```
git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
```

PS в следующий раз прежде чем задавать подобный вопрос просто зайдите на репозиторий и посмотрите ссылку на нужный вам проект

PSS и вместо произвольного набора тэгов лучше указывайте (для подобного типа вопросов) инструмент которым пользуетесь

Answer (score 0):

Одна команда... `git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git opencv`